# ImageView Toggle inside listview

Tags: android, listview, interface, adapter

I have a List view of ringtones with a play image view in each row for each ringtone ..

This is the view of it..

[image: Like this]

Now obviously when user clicks on a play button it should switch into pause button.. I have implemented this and it's all good so far ..

Now I have a problem :

I don't know how to track the currently playing row,I mean if user wants to play a song from another row, first I have to change currently pause toggle to play, then play the new one.

Can you help me with this please !?

**Interface**(In adapter)

```
       public interface PlayPauseClick {
         void playPauseOnClick(int position);
        }
   private PlayPauseClick callback;
   public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
        this.callback = listener;
    }
```

**Adapter**(In getView)

```
    Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);
    holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
    holder.playPause.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if (callback != null) {
                  callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
              }      
        }
    });
```

**Activity**

```
    @Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = productList.get(position);
                if (product.paused) {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    product.paused=false;
                }else {
                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    product.paused = true;
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the index of the current song which is played in the adapter.

So you just need to turn on pause when you click on an other button.

**In Adapter :**

```
int currentPosition = -1;
...
if (callback != null) {
  callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
  if (currentPosition == -1){
       currentPosition = position;
  } else if (currentPosition == position){
       currentPosition = -1;
  } else if (currentPosition != -1 && currentPosition != position){
       callback.playPauseOnClick(currentPosition);
       currentPosition = position;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's close to the answer , but once a play button clicked to pause button, it will not switch back to play button again..

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to solve this !? I will accept and vote your answer up ..

Comment: I just edited my post. When currentPosition is -1, no one button is in play.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the first problem ?

Comment: The main problem that I've asked a question for .. If user clicks the second row for playing a new song , previous icon will remain in pause icon

Answer (score 0):

Create in **Adapter** method

```
public void update (ArrayList<Product> productList) {
  this.productList.clear();
  this.productList.addAll(productList);
  notifyDataSetChanged();  
}
```

call method in **playPauseOnClick**

```
adapter.update(productList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This a solution:

In your activity create a class field `private Product mCurrentProduct;`

then :

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = productList.get(position);

                if (mCurrentProduct == null) {
                    mCurrentProduct = product)
                } 

                if (mCurrentProduct == product) {
                    if (product.paused) {
                       product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                       product.paused=false;
                    }else {
                       product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                       product.paused = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!mCurrentProduct.paused) {
                       product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                       product.paused = true;
                    }

                    product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    product.paused=false;

                    mCurrentProduct = product;
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    };
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my poor english.